# Integrate sikuli with selenoid to handle non html windows/Image based testing

Tags: selenoid

My scripts are working fine locally and same are not working with Chrome browser running in docker container of selenoid. How to integrate sikuli with Selenoid to handle file upload window(non HTML) in chrome browser which is running in docker container ?Any working example pls if it is possible

Comment: Without a single line of code it's hard to guess what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used sikuli  but here is what you can do to send file that is on your server, to the Selenoid browser

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.file_detector import LocalFileDetector
    
input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='file']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", input)
driver.file_detector = LocalFileDetector()
input.send_keys("/path/to/file/on/machine/which/runs/tests")
```